# algorithm to find best combination

Tags: algorithm, math

Assume that I have a list of 100 products, each of which has a price. Each one also has a energy (kJ) measurement.

Would it be possible to find the best combination of 15 products for under $10 of which the sum of the energy (kJ) was greatest, using programming?

I know C#, but any language is fine. Cheers.

**Update:** Having a bit of troble finding some sample source code for the knapsack issue. Does anyone have any or know where to find some. Been googling for a few hours and need to get this sorted by tomorrow if possible. Ta.

Comment: In this problem, you are presented with a collection of n prizes from which you are allowed to select at most m prizes, where m < n. Each prize p has a nonnegative integer value, denoted p.value. Your objective is to maximize the total value of your chosen prizes. The problem has several variations, described in parts (a)–(d) below. In each case, you should give an efficient algorithm to solve the problem, and analyze your algorithm’s time and space requirements. In parts (a)–(c), the prizes are presented to you as a sequence P = (p1, p2, . . . , pn), and your algorithm must output a subsequen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

> The **knapsack problem** or **rucksack problem** is a problem in [combinatorial optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization): Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible. It derives its name from the problem faced by someone who is constrained by a fixed-size [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack) and must fill it with the most valuable items...

Answer (score 7):

This sounds more like a [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem.

> Informally, linear programming
>   determines the way to achieve the best
>   outcome (such as maximum profit or
>   lowest cost) in a given mathematical
>   model and given some list of
>   requirements represented as linear
>   equations.

Check out the [Simplex Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

Comment: +1 Spot on. Check out lp_Solve. It is opensource, does what you need and has examples for a myriad of languages, including C#.

Comment: Won't this just give me the average price that the 15 products should be, not all the different prices which add to $10.

Answer (score 5):

This in Integer Linear Programming, optimizing a linear equation subject to linear constraints, where all the variables and coefficients are integers.

You want variables includeItem1, ..., includeItemN with constraints 0 ≤ includeItem*i* ≤ 1 for all values of *i*, and includeItem1 + ... + includeItemN ≤ 15, and includeItem1*priceItem1 + ... ≤ 10, maximizing includeItem1*kilojouleItem1 + ....

Stick that in your favorite integer linear program solver and get the solution :)

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

It doesn't make sense to say that your particular problem is NP-complete, but it's an instance of an NP-complete (kind of) problem, so there might not be a *theoretically* fast way of doing it.  Depending on how close to optimality you want to get and how fast ILP solvers work, it might be feasible in practice.

I don't think you problem is a special case of ILP that makes it particularly easy to solve.  Viewing it as a knapsack-like problem, you could restrict yourself to looking at all the subsets of 1..100 which have at most (or exactly) 15 elements, which is polynomial in n---it's n-choose-15, which is less than (n^15)/(15!), but that's not terribly useful when n = 100.

If you want recommendations for solver programs, I have tried glpk and found it pleasant to use.  In case you want something that costs money, my lecturer always talked about CPLEX as an example.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Could you go through the setup a bit more with the variables and constraints. I've never done this before so any extra help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have three variables per item: one is {0, 1} and indicates whether the variable is included in your set; the second is the price of the item, the third is the energy.  You then want to maximize the linear combination of "included" times "energy", subject to upper bounds on two other linr combns

Comment: s/variable/item/ at "is included in your set"

Answer (score 2):

That sounds a lot like the knapsack problem. There are various approaches (order descending by energy density, for example).

Answer (score 2):

This is the knapsack problem if you can either pick a product or not. If you can pick fractional values of products then you could solve this with the simplex method, but the fractional knapsack problem has a simple solution.

Order the items by energy/price ratio, picking 100% of the highest ones until you run out of money, then pick a fractional value of the highest remaining one.

For example if prices are 4,3,5,4 and energies are 3,5,2,7  the ordering is

7/4, 5/3, 3/4, 2/5

So you would pick items 4 and 2 which would cost 7$, with the 3$ remaining you would buy 75% of the first item for a price of $3 and an energy of 3*.75 = 2.25

This would give a total energy of 14.25

Note that allowing fractional values will give you a higher objective value than only allowing 0% or 100%, so no integer solution will do any better than 14.25 (or 14 for that matter since the objective value has to be an integer).

To solve the original knapsack problem, you can use a branch-and-bound which should work just fine in practice. Assume that you have a current candidate solution with an objective value of z*

1. Solve the relaxed problem, where you allow the fractional weights. If the value is less than z*, discard this branch.
2. Compute a new value z which is the solution found without the last fractional weight, if this value is greater than z* , replace z* with your new value
3. Pick one item (say the first in the list, the most profitable one) and form two subproblems, one where you **must** include it in the solution and one where you **cannot** include it in the solution (this is the branching step).
4. As long as you have subproblems left to solve, pick one and go back to step 1.

Note that when you create the subproblem where you must pick an item, just subtract its price from the budget and add the value to the profit, now you have a smaller problem to solve.

For a more detailed description look at [Branch and Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks Pall but you can't add a fractional product. You either add it or you don't.

Comment: It's still useful to "pretend" you could do it, since it gives you an upper bound on how well you could do. The branch and bound always keeps track of the best integer solution, it uses the fractional solution to reject branches that can't give you better than what you already have.

Answer (score 2):

The Stony Brook Algorithm Repository lists [implementations for the knapsack problem.](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/knapsack.shtml)

Their book [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693) has this kind of information for a vast array of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as everyone pointed out this is a complex knapsack problem.  Something this simple might be good enough though...

```
SELECT TOP 15 *
FROM Product
WHERE Price < 10
ORDER BY Energy DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the famous knapsack algorithm

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1):

Did something similar to this on a personal project, but in php code.
If you wish to port to c#, feel free.

This code takes into account the possibility of multiple combinations being the same, so the return value will be an array of `x` best results.

NOTE: This is taking in to account that any item can be used 0 or 1 times in each result

```
<?php
$products = [
    ['id' => 1, 'price' => 3.00, 'energy' => 200],
    ['id' => 2, 'price' => 14.10, 'energy' => 3200],
    ['id' => 3, 'price' => 2.66, 'energy' => 300],
    ['id' => 4, 'price' => 5.00, 'energy' => 450],
    ['id' => 5, 'price' => 6.23, 'energy' => 667],
    ['id' => 6, 'price' => 7.00, 'energy' => 1200]
];

function genCombinations($values, $count = 0)
{

    // Figure out how many combinations are possible:

    $comboCount = pow(count($values) , $count);
    $r = [];

    // Iterate and add to array

    for ($i = 0; $i < $comboCount; $i++){
        $r[] = getCombination($values, $count, $i);
    }
    return $r;
}


// State-based way of generating combinations:

function getCombination($values, $count, $index)
{
    $result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        // Figure out where in the array to start from, given the external state and the internal loop state

        $pos = $index % count($values);

        // Append and continue

        $result[] = $values[$pos];
        $index = ($index - $pos) / count($values);
    }
    return $result;
}

//maximize energy for given price

function getBestProductCombinations($products,$price_limit){

    //find all combinations where each product is either selected or not - true or false

    $combos = genCombinations([true,false],count($products));

    $results = [];
    foreach($combos as $combo){

        //loop through each combination and get a result

        $sum_price = 0;$items = [];$sum_energy = 0;
        foreach($combo as $i => $o){

            //loop through the array of true/false values determining if an item is on or off

            if($o){

                //if on, add item to result

                $sum_price += $products[$i]['price'];
                $sum_energy += $products[$i]['energy'];
                $items[] = $products[$i];
            }
        }
        if($sum_price <= $price_limit){

            //if sum of result is within the price limit, add to the results array

            $results[] = [
                'items' => $items,
                'price' => $sum_price,
                'energy' => $sum_energy
            ];
        }
    }

    $best = $results[0];$ra = [$best];
    foreach($results as $k => $result){
        if($k === 0){continue;}//skip first iteration as it was set above

        //check if the energy is higher than the best, or if equal, check if the price is better

        if($result['energy'] > $best['energy'] || ($result['energy'] === $best['energy'] && $result['price'] < $best['price'])){

            //reset best to the current result, reset return array

            $best = $result;
            $ra = [$best];
        }else if($result['energy'] === $best['energy']){

            //current result is the same as best, add it to the return array

            $ra[] = $result;
        }
    }
    return $ra;
}

echo '<pre>'.json_encode(getBestProductCombinations($products,10),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>';
```

Which then would give you:

```
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "price": 2.66,
                "energy": 300
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "price": 7,
                "energy": 1200
            }
        ],
        "price": 9.66,
        "energy": 1500
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to solve the problem with [Cream for Java](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/cream/). There's also a version for C# available [CSharpCream](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hmer200a/).